# JS Change hrefs to onclicks in HTML encoded entities

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-entities

I'm looping through a database that have strings that contain HTML entities:

`"<!-- SC_OFF --><div class=\"md\"><p>Here is an <a href=\"http://example.com\">example link</a></p>\n\n<p>Here is some body text for you with <sup>superscript</sup> and a bit of <strong>boldness</strong> and some <em>italics</em>. I forgot to mention this regular link here <a href=\"http://example.com\">http://example.com</a&gt; so don&#39;t forget that one. sometimes there can be more than one <a href=\"http://example.com\">formatted link</a> and <a href=\"http://example.com\">http://example.com</a></p&gt;\n\n<ul>\n<li>so there you go</li>\n<li>some sample text to work with</li>\n</ul>\n\n<p><del>strikethrough</del></p>\n\n<pre><code>if(canCode){\n    //lol dont kid yourself\n}\n</code></pre>\n</div><!-- SC_ON -->"`

that would be dynamically inserted into the DOM. I need to alter what the links do so basically all of these:

```
<a href="http://example.com">example</a>
```

becomes:

```
<a onClick="myFunc('http://example.com')">example</a>
```

You can find the decoded string here:

http://codepen.io/YikesItsMikes/pen/NxaJXg

but I figure editing the original text might be easier? I have no idea honestly :s

Comment: why do you want this change? do it in original code?

Comment: I dont have access to make changes in the database, its the endpoint of an api that I'm using to open up a sort of lightbox that contains other elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before inserting, you could run this `replace`:-

```
html = html.replace(/href=\"([^\"]+)\"/gi, 'onClick="myFunc(\'$1\')"')
```

using a group capture and `$1`

The group `( ... )` in the regex captures the value as `1` as `0` is always the full capture, in your case `href="http://example.com"`

In the second param then, you can use `$0` for the full, or `$1` for your capture group.

Comment: Perfect. I was looking for a simple string replacement solution like this

Answer (score 3):

After adding the html elements to DOM. Following code work (untested),

```
var $aTags = $('div.md').find('a');

$aTags.each(function() {
   var $aTag = $(this),
       href = $aTag.attr('href');
   $aTag.on('click',function(e) {
      myfunc(href);
      e.preventDefault();
   });
});
```

Updated code in your example (Tested)

```
var test = decodeHtml("&lt;!-- SC_OFF --&gt;&lt;div class=\"md\"&gt;&lt;p&gt;Here is an &lt;a href=\"http://example.com\"&gt;example link&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/p&gt;\n\n&lt;p&gt;Here is some body text for you with &lt;sup&gt;superscript&lt;/sup&gt; and a bit of &lt;strong&gt;boldness&lt;/strong&gt; and some &lt;em&gt;italics&lt;/em&gt;. I forgot to mention this regular link here &lt;a href=\"http://example.com\"&gt;http://example.com&lt;/a&gt; so don&amp;#39;t forget that one. sometimes there can be more than one &lt;a href=\"http://example.com\"&gt;formatted link&lt;/a&gt; and &lt;a href=\"http://example.com\"&gt;http://example.com&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/p&gt;\n\n&lt;ul&gt;\n&lt;li&gt;so there you go&lt;/li&gt;\n&lt;li&gt;some sample text to work with&lt;/li&gt;\n&lt;/ul&gt;\n\n&lt;p&gt;&lt;del&gt;strikethrough&lt;/del&gt;&lt;/p&gt;\n\n&lt;pre&gt;&lt;code&gt;if(canCode){\n    //lol dont kid yourself\n}\n&lt;/code&gt;&lt;/pre&gt;\n&lt;/div&gt;&lt;!-- SC_ON --&gt;")

$(document.body).append(test);

var $aTags = $('div.md').find('a');

$aTags.each(function() {
   var $aTag = $(this),
       href = $aTag.attr('href');
   $aTag.on('click',function(e) {
     myfunc(href);
     e.preventDefault();
   }); 
});

function myfunc(href) {
  alert(href);
}

function decodeHtml(html) {
   var txt = document.createElement("textarea");
   txt.innerHTML = html;
   return txt.value;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('a').each(function () {
    var href = $(this).prop('href');
    $(this).click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        myFunc(href);
    });
    $(this).removeProp('href');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function myFunction(link) {
  console.log(link)
}

var html = "<!-- SC_OFF --><div class=\"md\"><p>Here is an <a href=\"http://example.com\">example link</a></p>\n\n<p>Here is some body text for you with <sup>superscript</sup> and a bit of <strong>boldness</strong> and some <em>italics</em>. I forgot to mention this regular link here <a href=\"http://example.com\">http://example.com</a&gt; so don&#39;t forget that one. sometimes there can be more than one <a href=\"http://example.com\">formatted link</a> and <a href=\"http://example.com\">http://example.com</a></p&gt;\n\n<ul>\n<li>so there you go</li>\n<li>some sample text to work with</li>\n</ul>\n\n<p><del>strikethrough</del></p>\n\n<pre><code>if(canCode){\n    //lol dont kid yourself\n}\n</code></pre>\n</div><!-- SC_ON -->";

$(html).filter(":not(comment)")
.find("a").each(function() {
  var link = this.href;
  $(this)
  .attr({"href": "#", "onclick":"myFunction('"+link+"')"}) 
}).addBack().appendTo("body")
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

     var szData="<div class=\"md\"><p>Here is an <a href=\"http://example.com\">example</a></p>\n\n<p>Here is some body text for you with <sup>superscript</sup> and a bit of <strong>boldness</strong> and some <em>italics</em>. I forgot to mention this regular link here <a href=\"http://example.com\">http://example.com</a&gt; so don&#39;t forget that one. sometimes there can be more than one <a href=\"http://example.com\">formatted link</a> and <a href=\"http://example.com\">http://example.com</a></p&gt;\n\n<ul>\n<li>so there you go</li>\n<li>some sample text to work with</li>\n</ul>\n\n<p><del>strikethrough</del></p>\n\n<pre><code>if(canCode){\n    //lol dont kid yourself\n}\n</code></pre>\n</div>"


     $('.content').html(szData);

     $('.content').find('a').each(function () {


         $(this).on('click', function (e) {
             myfunc($(this).attr('href'));
             e.preventDefault();
         });

         $(this).removeAttr('href');
     });


     function myfunc(szhref)
     {
         alert('myfunc')
     }
});
```